# multiple simultaneous outputs arduino mega without array

Tags: arduino

Is there a simple method to enable multiple outputs on arduino mega at same time without using an array or registers. I just want two outputs to go high at same time over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

without using registers, it seems hard.

registers are pretty *simple*:

depending on the ports you want to set high, it will look like this (from Arduino website):

```
PORTD = B10101000; // sets digital pins 7,5,3 HIGH
```